# How to require users to signup with a specific type of email address in Ruby on Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How would I go about requiring users to signup to a website with a specific type of email address (e.g. User@college.edu)? If you could provide what type of validations would be needed in the model as well as any other requirements this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FrederickCheung commented,the accepted answer allows you to singup with the formats like

```
abc@college.edu.xyz.com
```

Instead try with this `REGEXP` in your user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :email, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+edu)\z/ }

end
```

This will make sure the domain name ends with `edu` only.

Comment: I think you could still sign up with .edu.something - you're not anchoring the regex at the end

Comment: @FrederickCheung Ohh,I just tested in rubular.com and it is matching the formats like `xyz@abc.edu` or `xyz123@abc.edu` and If i'm wrong please edit my post to make it correct.

Comment: Yes, but it also matches abc@college.edu.xyz.com. I've added an end of string marker for you

Answer (score 1):

Use a normal validation for email format, and then use a second validation for email name

```
class User < AR

  # first we validate email with a regex
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /@/

  # then make validations over the name 
  validate :validate_college

  def validate_college
    errors.add("invalid college") unless self.email.include?( "@college.edu" )
  end

end
```

regards

Comment: note that the first regex for format validation is up to you , I take the example from http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: You might consider changing that to checking that the email ends with the string - I could currently sign up with fred@college.edu.arandomdomain.com

Comment: @FrederickCheung Might this work? `^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}|edu)$` untested though.need your comments.

Comment: @FrederickCheung scratch that i got it this  works `/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+edu)/` tested.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just add a validates method to the class and feed it a regex that only takes specific types of email addresses. Such as one that checks the last three characters to ensure that they "edu" or similar.

Comment: how would a validation like so look. Could you provide an example with a class of User?